# How can I resolve this custom error redirect in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

I want to redirect all url errors

The url I want to cath is ~/bla/foo

It should redirect to ~/error404.aspx

bla exists as a folder. foo does not exist.

I already set the webconfig to point to my error but I just doesn't work. I get this error:

```
Server Error in application /.
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------

The source can not be found.
Description: HTTP 404. Perhaps you are looking for the source (or a dependency thereof)     removed or is temporarily unavailable or has changed its name. Check the spelling of the URL.

Requested URL: / bla/foo.asox
```

I google translate this error cuz VS here is language specific.

What can I do to resolve this??? I want to point to ~/error404.aspx

Comment: The error says you are going to `/ bla/foo.asox`, not `/bla/foo` as you state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also configure a custom 404 page in [IIS (this example is IIS 6)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/80cb8d8d-8fd8-4af5-bb3b-4d11fff3ab9c.mspx).  That way request for any resource that doesn't exist will go to your custom error404.aspx page.

There's also a walk through here with [screen shots here](http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=11) if that helps.  This would be something you configure outside of your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the 404 message to a custom one, here are the steps to override the default one:

You can use:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages.aspx

There are more details in the link which show you exactly how to catch the 404 error and handle it.